# Update to a newer version of OS X from OS X 10.6.8

Tags: macos, software-update

Every time I click Software Update it tells me there's no new software! I don't even know what software I'm running so I can't search for updated software. Why is it stuck on 10.6.8?

Comment: We really need more details - like what Mac it is

Comment: macbook. i dont know what else to tell you :/

Comment: Apple menu > About this Mac - at least the full model name or build year [I don't remember what About this Mac looked like so long ago]

Comment: Model Name: MacBook
  Model Identifier: MacBook4,1
  Processor Name: Intel Core 2 Duo
  Processor Speed: 2.1 GHz
  Number Of Processors: 1
  Total Number Of Cores: 2
  L2 Cache: 3 MB
  Memory: 4 GB
  Bus Speed: 800 MHz
  Boot ROM Version: MB41.00C1.B00
  SMC Version (system): 1.31f1
  Serial Number (system): W88130BN0P0
  Hardware UUID: 342F3C70-3631-5D20-A5D3-D089DAEB46C0
  Sudden Motion Sensor:
  State: Enabled

Comment: OK, that machine can run OS 10.7.5 - see [Everymac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook/specs/macbook-core-2-duo-2.1-white-13-early-2008-penryn-specs.html) for full specs. Have you tried launching the App Store app specifically [in Applications] - the update mechanism changed at around the time your OS was released.

Comment: I dont know how to do that, download applications on my macbook, i've tried in the past but couldn't figure out how to do it.
I just went into everymac but not sure what im looking for? I have no idea when it comes to computers...

Comment: Look in the Applications folder - double click App Store. Click the Updates tab.

Comment: ok i went into app store and clicked on update and it came up with yosimite so when i clicked update it said it cant update on my computer!

Comment: You might have to search for Lion instead. It's no longer generally on offer but might still be available if that's the latest your machine can run.

Comment: just checked it doesnt come up with Lion. Actually i have the software discs can i just reinstall it, will that help solve the problem?

Comment: That would just put you back to square one. I'm guessing mostly that the reason you see no updates is that OS is no longer supported so most things you are running don't have updates that will run on it any more. Updating to Lion might open up a few possibilities.

Comment: So the only solution is to purchase the new software?

Comment: Not if it will no longer run on that machine. Basically, it's end-of-life; you pretty much have to stick with what you have.

Comment: You won't be able to run anything newer than 10.7.x, so buying Yosemite won't help you.

Comment: Ah ok so its the machine that needs updating! Thank you for all your help...

Comment: I'm afraid so, if you need to be running current versions of software.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, Lion (10.7) is the latest version of OS X supported by your machine. Although it's no longer available for download from the App Store, you can still order the media [from the Apple Store](http://store.apple.com/us/product/D6106Z/A/os-x-lion).